# Is there a way to check how many messages one user sent in a server in a certain amount of time with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I’d like to add a command that checks how many messages a user sent in the entire server in the last x amount of time (say, a week).

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd have to use the [`TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) method for each text channel, filter the messages by checking for that user as the author, and add up the number of messages yourself.